# Install Ubuntu on HP mini HP2133

Tags: installation, boot, usb, hp

I wanted to install Ubuntu on a HP mini (HP 2133). I created an USB bootable stick (1.9Gb) with Ubuntu desktop 13.10 32-bit version using Universal USB installer 1.9.5.2 (I also checked the box to format the USB stick).
I booted from the USB stick (press F9 at startup). The "Ubuntu 13.10" logo appeared with the 4-dot progress bar underneath. After a while I could see a few screens with unrecognizable character (Matrix style :)) and then there is the cursor blinking on the top left side on a black screen. And nothing happens.
I tried several times with the same result. Do you have any idea why and how can I pass this?

Comment: Do you have which version of firmware? is it F.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 12.04 instead solved the issue.